# How to configure dscp on protocol SCTP

Tags: sctp, dscp

I want to know how to configure DSCP on protocol SCTP in SUSE. I have searched Google and found this command:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 10.29.48.44  -p TCP -j DSCP --set-dscp 0x30
```

After I execute it and tcpump, I find it worked and DSCP was set to CS6.

I use the same command and only replace TCP with SCTP and execute it:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 10.29.48.44  -p SCTP -j DSCP --set-dscp 0x30
```

I tested and found it didn't work, the DSCP didn't change.